# how is mysql working?

Tags: mysql, database

I have basic knowledge in mysql. But I want more. I mean, "If I enter a query, how was  the mysql server processing it and put the result", like that.
What I exactly want, how does mysql server read .frm file?
Anyone refer me the link for that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to look into the Execution plan to know how the RDBMS works internally, try this as a starting point:  [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you try writing a query, just issue the following command and see

```
Explain <select statement>
```

This by default gives you the elaborate details of what is going to happen when you actually execute a query. Very helpful in debugging as well as improving the performance of queries.

Comment: What I exactly want, how does mysql server read .frm file?

Comment: The .frm files are data files that MySQL uses to store your tables. To query them you need to connect to the MySQL server using a client, such as MySQL Query Browser, which you can download from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/query-browser/. The .frm file doesn't really contain any data, it's just the table definition, metadata and all the data is contained in the ibdata file for InnoDB database engine or .myd files for MyISAM engine.  So once you have a connection established, you can just directly query from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get information from below link

http://ece.ut.ac.ir/dbrg/seminars/AdvancedDB/Fall%202008/hashemi/Project_MySQL_Benchmark/References/MySQL%20Conceptual%20Architecture.pdf

Comment: This pdf useful for me. It has done with theoretical only, but I want practical. For example :- About Query parser given in this pdf , "In this stage, the objective of the query parser is to
create a parse tree structure based on the query so that it can be easily understood by the other components
later in the pipeline." 
But I want what is happening inside the query parser(Not only the definition).